# Create new array using JSON results with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hello I have the following JSON result. Its a small snippet from a large JSON file. Theres hundreds of entries.

```
var jsonResult = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "one",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "two",
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "three",
    }
]
```

I would like a way to loop through this data using javascript to create a new array stored in a variable that pulls just the ids. So the new array would look like this:

```
data = [1, 2, 3];
```

If theres 1000 entries, then the array would go from 1-1000.

Thanks!

Comment: This is very simple using a variety of different loop approaches. Please show what you have tried. There are also many other similar questions on SO

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/1220550

Comment: man you guys are ruthless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple just use array.map.

```js
var jsonResult = [
  {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "one",
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "two",
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "three",
  }
]

let idArray = jsonResult.map(element => element["id"]);
console.log(idArray)
```

Comment: thank you this works perfectly